# Changing Command Bar Size in D365 2016

Tags: resize, dynamics-crm, commandbar

I'm trying to change the size of the command bar in a D365 2016 (v8.2) environment. We essentially want to make if smaller, and the buttons closer together. We recently migrated to a new server and now the command bar is larger:
[image: Command Bar]

I've looked into Ribbon Workbench, but it doesn't seem to have that capability, and the site map editor doesn't touch this. Co-workers have said it can't be done. Any ideas?